# PhpStorm define collapsible code regions (Visual Studio style Regions) possible?

Tags: folding, phpstorm

In Visual Studio you can use `#region` and `#endregion` to wrap developer defined blocks of code.

I would love to see this functionality in PhpStorm, it is an ideal way to organise a large source file (for example lots of interface implementations).

Is it possible to make PhpStorm behave this way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<s>Sorry, currently it is not possible.</s>

<s>Please vote and watch this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-261</s>

---

**UPDATE**

It's now implemented (**since PhpStorm v4**) -- check PhpStorm's blog for details: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/

---

```
//<editor-fold desc="Region">

// Your code goes here

//</editor-fold>
```

Default collapse state is also properly supported now (as of PhpStorm v8, IIRC), although you have to add such part yourself manually. e.g.

```
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Region">
```

---

**P.S.** `#region` syntax ([Old MSDN link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905165948/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9a1ybwek(v=vs.80).aspx) / [current 2022 docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-regions)) is also supported.

Comment: It works now, BTW. At least in the EAP build. Just surround your code in `#region` and `#endregion`.

Comment: @Nate See updated answer with correct link: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/new-in-4-0-custom-code-folding-regions/

Comment: @LazyOne Ah thanks - Would also like to note `#range` and `region` also work for folding

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for this too, and find that it's available for use now in version 4 EAP.

Working example:

```
// region Private members
private $db;
private $cache;
// endregion
```

Comment: This is a great way of doing it over using tags! More like VS which in my opinion do them very well.

Comment: This is the easiest way！